android studio sync fails while ./gradlew works just as fine
I am trying to sync and build Jetchat project which is a part of jetpack compose samples.
I cloned the repo and tries to sync it using android studio. he problem is that when i want to sync it android studio shows error like this.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Jetchat'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find core-proto-0.0.9-alpha02.jar (com.google.testing.platform:core-proto:0.0.9-alpha02).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/testing/platform/core-proto/0.0.9-alpha02/core-proto-0.0.9-alpha02.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

but when i run ./gradlew build or ./gradlew assemble or ./gradlew assembleDebug everything is just fine and I get a decent APK of the project.
anybody can help me I appreciate it.
ps
*my android studio is Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2
*I set android studio gradle on jvm 17 and 11 and nothing helped
*I invalidated and restarted
*clean rebuild did not help
no idea what to do
